# SharePoint Online, OneDrive sync, maintain folder hierarchy

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, onedrive-for-business, sync, onedrive

I have created a site "Clients" in SharePoint Online that has a subsite for every client and they have to contribute access to all document libraries on that site, they can't access other client sites.

I want to sync OneDrive with a document library. OneDrive creates a folder for every document library at root, can we maintain the hierarchy as we have in SharePoint online sites? For example, there should be a folder "Clients" within that there should be a folder for every client and then inside that folder all document libraries for that client?